# Is it necessary to submit my bank statement which does not have funds?

Tags: schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds, schengen-visas

Since I'm being I'm being supported by my friend in Germany ,is it still necessary to submit my bank statement which do not have funds ? And will I be granted a visa if I submit it?

Comment: We know that you are applying for a Shengen visa to Germany. You could be helpful and remind us however.  Also... We do not engage in prophecies here, see a fortune teller.  Honestly, who knows if your application will be successful. Ask a question with a single technically correct answer and we'll try to help. Close voting as misconceived, unclear, opinion-based.

Comment: Your German friend can sign a [*Verpflichtungserklärung*](https://www.frankfurt.de/sixcms/detail.php?id=703665&_ffmpar%5B_id_inhalt%5D=7003780) which means he either deposits money for all possible costs (accommodation or subsistence) in advance (it will be more than 3 000 €) or he discloses his/her financial situation and proves that he is able to cover the costs. In this case the bank statement will not be necessary.